# Is this a bug with UTF conversion in GNAT Ada

Tags: ada, gnat

I am trying to convert from UTF 16 to UTF 8; this is a test program:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding.Conversions;
use Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Strings.Utf_Encoding.Conversions;
use Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding;

procedure Main is
   Str_8: UTF_8_String := "";
   Str_16: UTF_16_Wide_String := Convert(Str_8);
   Str_8_New: UTF_8_String := Convert(Str_16);
begin
   if Str_8 = Str_8_New then
      Put_Line("OK");
   else
      Put_Line("Bug");
   end if;
end Main;
```

With latest GNAT community it prints "Bug". Is this a bug in the implementation of UTF conversion functions or am I doing something wrong here?

Edit: For reference, this issue has been accepted as [Bug 95953](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95953) / [Bug 95959](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95959).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mismatch between the 3rd byte of `Str_8` and `Str_8_New` which causes the round-trip to fail. This seems a bug.

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

with Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding.Conversions;

use Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding;
use Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding.Conversions;

procedure Main is
         
   --  UTF8 encoded Clef (U+1D11E)
   --  (e.g.) https://unicode-table.com/en/1D11E/
   
   Str_8 : constant UTF_8_String :=
     Character'Val (16#F0#) &
     Character'Val (16#9D#) &
     Character'Val (16#84#) &
     Character'Val (16#9E#);

   Str_16    : constant UTF_16_Wide_String := Convert (Str_8);
   Str_8_New : constant UTF_8_String       := Convert (Str_16);
   
begin      
   for I in Str_8'Range loop
      Put (Character'Pos (Str_8 (I)), 7, 16);
   end loop;
   New_Line (2);   
   
   for I in Str_16'Range loop
      Put (Wide_Character'Pos (Str_16 (I)), 9, 16);
   end loop;
   New_Line (2);
   
   for I in Str_8_New'Range loop
      Put (Character'Pos (Str_8_New (I)), 7, 16);
   end loop;
   New_Line (2);
   
end Main;
```

**output**

```
$ ./main
 16#F0# 16#9D# 16#84# 16#9E#

 16#D834# 16#DD1E#

 16#F0# 16#9D# 16#90# 16#9E#
```

Answer (score 4):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62570233/230513), @DeeDee has identified a bug in the implementation of [`Convert`](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-11.html) for `UTF_16` to `UTF_8`. The problem arises in byte three of the four byte value for code points in the range `U+10000` to `U+10FFFF`, shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description). The [source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/c9c05f7323f2d92252c46aea042a2c2d5b11a4dd/gcc/ada/libgnat/a-suenco.adb#L357) documents the relevant bit fields:

```
--  Codes in the range 16#10000# - 16#10FFFF#
--    UTF-16: 110110zzzzyyyyyy 110111yyxxxxxxxx
--    UTF-8:  11110zzz 10zzyyyy 10yyyyxx 10xxxxxx
--    Note: zzzzz in the output is input zzzz + 1
```

Byte three is constructed as follows:

```
Result (Len + 3) :=
  Character'Val
    (2#10_000000# or Shift_Left (yyyyyyyy and 2#1111#, 4)
                  or Shift_Right (xxxxxxxx, 6));
```

While the low four bits of `yyyyyyyy` are used to construct byte three, the value only needs to be shifted *two* places left to make room for the top two bits of `xxxxxxxx`. The correct formulation should be this:

```
Result (Len + 3) :=
  Character'Val
    (2#10_000000# or Shift_Left (yyyyyyyy and 2#1111#, 2)
                  or Shift_Right (xxxxxxxx, 6));
```

For reference, the complete example below recapitulates the original implementation, with enough additions to study the problem in isolation. The output shows the code point, the expected binary representation of the `UTF-8` encoding, the conversion to `UTF-16`, the incorrect `UTF-8` conversion, and the correct `UTF-8` conversion.

```
Codepoint: 16#1D11E#
 UTF-8: 4: 2#11110000# 2#10011101# 2#10000100# 2#10011110#
UTF-16: 2: 2#1101100000110100# 2#1101110100011110#
 UTF-8: 4: 2#11110000# 2#10011101# 2#10010000# 2#10011110#
 UTF-8: 4: 2#11110000# 2#10011101# 2#10000100# 2#10011110#
OK
```

Code:

```
-- https://stackoverflow.com/q/62564638/230513
with Ada.Text_IO;              use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;      use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding; use Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding;
with Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding.Conversions;
   use Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding.Conversions;
with Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding.Wide_Wide_Strings;
   use Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding.Wide_Wide_Strings;
with Interfaces; use Interfaces;
with Unchecked_Conversion;

procedure UTFTest is
   -- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d11e/index.htm
   Clef : constant Wide_Wide_String :=
     (1 => Wide_Wide_Character'Val (16#1D11E#));
   Str_8     : constant UTF_8_String       := Encode (Clef);
   Str_16    : constant UTF_16_Wide_String := Convert (Str_8);
   Str_8_New : constant UTF_8_String       := Convert (Str_16);
   My_Str_8  : UTF_8_String                := Convert (Str_16);

   function To_Unsigned_16 is new Unchecked_Conversion (Wide_Character,
      Interfaces.Unsigned_16);

   procedure Raise_Encoding_Error (Index : Natural) is
      Val : constant String := Index'Img;
   begin
      raise Encoding_Error
        with "bad input at Item (" & Val (Val'First + 1 .. Val'Last) & ')';
   end Raise_Encoding_Error;

   function My_Convert (Item : UTF_16_Wide_String;
      Output_BOM             : Boolean := False) return UTF_8_String
   is
      Result : UTF_8_String (1 .. 3 * Item'Length + 3);
      --  Worst case is 3 output codes for each input code + BOM space

      Len : Natural;
      --  Number of result codes stored

      Iptr : Natural;
      --  Pointer to next input character

      C1, C2 : Unsigned_16;

      zzzzz    : Unsigned_16;
      yyyyyyyy : Unsigned_16;
      xxxxxxxx : Unsigned_16;
      --  Components of double length case

   begin
      Iptr := Item'First;

      --  Skip BOM at start of input

      if Item'Length > 0 and then Item (Iptr) = BOM_16 (1) then
         Iptr := Iptr + 1;
      end if;

      --  Generate output BOM if required

      if Output_BOM then
         Result (1 .. 3) := BOM_8;
         Len             := 3;
      else
         Len := 0;
      end if;

      --  Loop through input

      while Iptr <= Item'Last loop
         C1   := To_Unsigned_16 (Item (Iptr));
         Iptr := Iptr + 1;

         --  Codes in the range 16#0000# - 16#007F#
         --    UTF-16: 000000000xxxxxxx
         --    UTF-8:  0xxxxxxx

         if C1 <= 16#007F# then
            Result (Len + 1) := Character'Val (C1);
            Len              := Len + 1;

            --  Codes in the range 16#80# - 16#7FF#
            --    UTF-16: 00000yyyxxxxxxxx
            --    UTF-8:  110yyyxx 10xxxxxx

         elsif C1 <= 16#07FF# then
            Result (Len + 1) :=
              Character'Val (2#110_00000# or Shift_Right (C1, 6));
            Result (Len + 2) :=
              Character'Val (2#10_000000# or (C1 and 2#00_111111#));
            Len := Len + 2;

            --  Codes in the range 16#800# - 16#D7FF# or 16#E000# - 16#FFFF#
            --    UTF-16: yyyyyyyyxxxxxxxx
            --    UTF-8:  1110yyyy 10yyyyxx 10xxxxxx

         elsif C1 <= 16#D7FF# or else C1 >= 16#E000# then
            Result (Len + 1) :=
              Character'Val (2#1110_0000# or Shift_Right (C1, 12));
            Result (Len + 2) :=
              Character'Val
                (2#10_000000# or (Shift_Right (C1, 6) and 2#00_111111#));
            Result (Len + 3) :=
              Character'Val (2#10_000000# or (C1 and 2#00_111111#));
            Len := Len + 3;

            --  Codes in the range 16#10000# - 16#10FFFF#
            --    UTF-16: 110110zzzzyyyyyy 110111yyxxxxxxxx
            --    UTF-8:  11110zzz 10zzyyyy 10yyyyxx 10xxxxxx
            --    Note: zzzzz in the output is input zzzz + 1

         elsif C1 <= 2#110110_11_11111111# then
            if Iptr > Item'Last then
               Raise_Encoding_Error (Iptr - 1);
            else
               C2   := To_Unsigned_16 (Item (Iptr));
               Iptr := Iptr + 1;
            end if;

            if (C2 and 2#111111_00_00000000#) /= 2#110111_00_00000000# then
               Raise_Encoding_Error (Iptr - 1);
            end if;

            zzzzz    := (Shift_Right (C1, 6) and 2#1111#) + 1;
            yyyyyyyy :=
              ((Shift_Left (C1, 2) and 2#111111_00#) or
               (Shift_Right (C2, 8) and 2#000000_11#));
            xxxxxxxx := C2 and 2#11111111#;

            Result (Len + 1) :=
              Character'Val (2#11110_000# or (Shift_Right (zzzzz, 2)));
            Result (Len + 2) :=
              Character'Val
                (2#10_000000# or Shift_Left (zzzzz and 2#11#, 4) or
                 Shift_Right (yyyyyyyy, 4));
            Result (Len + 3) :=
              Character'Val
                (2#10_000000# or Shift_Left (yyyyyyyy and 2#1111#, 2) or
                 Shift_Right (xxxxxxxx, 6));
            Result (Len + 4) :=
              Character'Val (2#10_000000# or (xxxxxxxx and 2#00_111111#));
            Len := Len + 4;

         --  Error if input in 16#DC00# - 16#DFFF# (2nd surrogate with no 1st)

         else
            Raise_Encoding_Error (Iptr - 2);
         end if;
      end loop;

      return Result (1 .. Len);
   end My_Convert;

   procedure Show (S : String) is
   begin
      Put(" UTF-8: ");
      Put (S'Length, 1);
      Put (":");
      for C of S loop
         Put (Character'Pos (C), 12, 2);
      end loop;
      New_Line;
   end Show;

   procedure Show (S : Wide_String) is
   begin
      Put("UTF-16: ");
      Put (S'Length, 1);
      Put (":");
      for C of S loop
         Put (Wide_Character'Pos (C), 20, 2);
      end loop;
      New_Line;
   end Show;

begin
   Put ("Codepoint:");
   Put (Wide_Wide_Character'Pos (Clef (1)), 10, 16);
   New_Line;
   Show (Str_8);
   Show (Str_16);
   Show (Str_8_New);
   My_Str_8 := My_Convert (Str_16);
   Show (My_Str_8);
   if Str_8 = My_Str_8 then
      Put_Line ("OK");
   else
      Put_Line ("Bug");
   end if;
end UTFTest;
```

See also [Bug 95953](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95953) / [Bug 95959](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95959).